# How to create a stream from Cassandra DB?

Tags: websocket, cassandra, real-time

I've been trying to create something like a chat app or a notification system, anything that can "stream" from Cassandra.

I thought about making something like (wannabe pseudocode):

```
function newMessage() {
  addToCassandra(fromUser, room, message, time)
  sendToClient(fromUser, room, message, time)
}
```

But There is kafka, storm, etc and I'm not sure what would be the most efficient way of doing this.

I got a static server to serve a vuejs app and an API server that serve all ajax/websocket requests with graphql (and 3 cassandra servers).

A new user could just grab from the cassandra db for history and connect to the websocket to have new notifications/messages.

What would be the best way of achieving reasltime or near real time notification and chat?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to get streamed updates from cassandra is via polling from your app. And that adds a lot of complexity to make item ordering and deduplication (it is implemented in [journal plugin for akka-persistence](https://github.com/akka/akka-persistence-cassandra/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/cassandra/journal/CassandraJournal.scala), you may checkout the amount of code). I'd recommend using some db with notification support ([foundation](https://www.foundationdb.org/) or [rethink](https://www.rethinkdb.com/)) though they have their own pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks! RethinkDb it is Ilove that one. I was led to think companies was using cassandra for real time stuff. Ill implement notifications and chat in rethink. Thanks for your answer